# Robot Framework-Run Firefox with profile

Tags: firefox, robotframework

Created a firefox profile, and provided the dir path in my script like below

[image: this is my script]

But it says its unable to find the path[image]

I am unable to run my scripts in FF, please help

Comment: Can we see the contents of your `C:\Python27\FF_PROFILE`?

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping single slashes

```
C:\\Python27\\FF_PROFILE
```